# Mining with a Lenovo Ideapad Y580 (GeForce GTX660M card with Optimus)

Tags: ubuntu, miner-configuration

I wanted to do some mining with my IdeaPad Y580 which has a NVIDIA GeForce GTX660M and Intel HD 4000 integrated graphics, switched using Optimus. Laptop is running under Ubuntu 13.04.

The problem is i can't launch a miner (i tried cgminer and poclbm) on the laptop. I usually get the error like 'Nothing to mine on, exiting', or something similar.

The question is, how can I configure the miner/OpenCL to get this working.

Also I know that NVIDIAs/laptop graphics are ineffective in BTC mining, I just wanted to see how many Mhashes does my card get.

Comment: Got OpenCL installed?

Answer (score 1):

Both the GeForce and the Intel HD 4000 should be OpenCL capable and possible to mine on.

The problem may be crippled drivers. I know HP and Dell make their "own" AMD drivers, meaning they take AMDs drivers and remove OpenCL support. Proper drivers from amd.com often refuse to install on those laptops. That's HP and Dell "helping you" by breaking your computer. Maybe Lenovo does the same with Nvidia drivers?

I would try to install the latest drivers from nvidia.com

For the Intel HD 4000 you could try getting drivers from http://www.intel.com/p/en_US/support/detect/graphics or even installing their OpenCL SDK from http://software.intel.com/en-us/vcsource/tools/opencl-sdk although I think that should not be necessary.

Comment: Oh. I forgot to say that I'm on Ubuntu 13.04, and I use drivers from the official repo.

Comment: I think you'll need proprietary drivers from nvidia.com - I believe the open source drivers don't have OpenCL support.

Comment: I am using the proprietary drivers - they come from a Ubuntu official repository.

Comment: I'd try drivers from nvidia.com

Comment: I'm getting 40mh/s on windows casual mining with bitminter client on this laptop, is that typical or additional opencl drivers will improve this?

Comment: @sonjz In 2015 if you are mining on a computer you earn less than the electricity costs, so the more you mine the more money you lose. It's also so slow that you never earn enough to cash out. Look up bitcoin ASIC mining hardware instead.

Comment: @Dr.Haribo thanks for the reply.  Yeah I started to look at the calculations, I had mistakenly thought I was getting 40GH/s, even so, after looking at the numbers again, probably not worth my while at the moment.